# Does the number of files affect fsck's performance?

Tags: linux, performance, fsck

Will a 100GB disk with 1,000,000 files take longer than a 100GB disk with 100 files when running `fsck`?

Comment: To be clear: Would the 1,000,000 files and the 100 files occupy the same amount of space?

Comment: @Dennis Yes, same space occupied.

Comment: most likely it will be slower.  It has to go through the list of filenames 1 at a time and verify they are correct.  How much slower is also dependent on the file system, and hard drive speed and processor speed.  Also if the filesystem code is code for multi threaded or not.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

That depends on the file system and the switches you use with fsck.

[What `fsck` Checks and Tries to Repair](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/E19455-01/805-7228/6j6q7uf0e/index.html) gives a pretty detailed explanation of what fsck does when invoked without switches.

Some of the checks take a constant amount of time (e.g., super block check),  many of them depend on the number of inodes fsck has to process (e.g., link count checks), others on the file system's size (e.g., regular data block checks).

Without the `-c` switch, fsck does not check the contents of regular files, so the size of the files is irrelevant. Even when checking for bad blocks, the execution time only increases with the file system's size. Which portion of the of the partition is occupied does not affect the execution time.<sup>1</sup>

The number of [inodes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inode) of a file system is constant, i.e., decided upon at creation time. Each file's metadata is stored in one of such inodes. According to [ext4](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ext4), unused inodes are marked as such in ext4, but not in ext3. Thus, fsck's execution time increases with the file count in ext4, but is constant (and high) in ext3.

The following figure illustrates this:

[image: comparison]

Observe that the different file counts are represented by different colors. The graphs for ext3 with 2.1 million, 100 thousand and even zero files are identical. The graph for ext4 with 2.1M and 100k files respectively show a significant difference.

In contrast, execution time increases with the number of inodes with ext3, while unused inode do not impact execution time with ext4.

---

<sub><sup>1</sup></sub> Verified empirically by running `fsck -c` on an empty partition.